# Find the longest "common sequence" in two lists

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

In short, the algorithm must find the longest sequence that joins together common sequences from two lists (a more formal specification is given in the code's header).

The lists are assumed to contain the same elements without duplicates.

Example: from `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `[1,4,5,2,6,3]` the algorithm should return `[1,4,5,6]`.

Does the algorithm look correct, and did I miss any optimization?

```js
// Find the longest sequence seq such that :
// for all i, there exists j and k such that seq[i]=list1[j]=list2[k]
// and seq[i+1]=list1[j']=list2[k'] where j < j' and k < k'.
//
// Precondition : list1 and list2 contain the same elements without duplicates.
//
function findMaxCommonSequence(list1, list2) {
    let indexList2 = {}; // Provides O(1) access to the indice in list2 for a given element
    list2.forEach ((elt, i) => indexList2[elt] = i);

    // i1 is the starting indices in list1
    function find (i1) {
        let currentVal = list1[i1];
        let prefix = [currentVal];
        let ignore = new Set (prefix);
        let maxLength = 1;
        let maxSequence = prefix;
        let i2 = indexList2[currentVal]; // i2 is the starting indices in list2
        // Iterate through list1, stopping when we don't have enough remaining elements
        // to improve on the longest sequence found so far (subsumes the boundary check)
        while (list1.length-i1 > maxLength) {
            ++ i1;
            // Only consider the elements that are further into list2
            // and are not part of an already explored solution
            if (indexList2[list1[i1]] > i2 && !ignore.has (list1[i1])) {
                let rec = find (i1);
                let sequence = prefix.concat (rec.maxSequence);
                ignore = new Set ([...ignore, ...rec.ignore]);
                if (sequence.length > maxLength) {
                    maxLength = sequence.length;
                    maxSequence = sequence;
                }
            }
        }
        return {
            maxSequence: maxSequence,
            ignore: ignore,
        };
    }
    
    // Outer loop on the same principle as find() except we don't have a prefix
    let i1 = 0;
    let ignore = new Set ();
    let maxLength = 0;
    let maxSequence = [];
    while (list1.length-i1 > maxLength) {
        if (!ignore.has (list1[i1])) {
            let rec = find (i1);
            let sequence = rec.maxSequence;
            ignore = new Set ([...ignore, ...rec.ignore]);
            if (sequence.length > maxLength) {
                maxLength = sequence.length;
                maxSequence = sequence;
            }
        }
        ++ i1;
    }
    
    return maxSequence;
}


console.log("[1,2,3,4,5,6] + [1,4,5,2,6,3] -> [1,4,5,6] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,4,5,2,6,3])));
            
console.log("[1,4,5,2,6,3] + [1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [1,4,5,6] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence([1,4,5,2,6,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6])));

console.log("[1,4,5,2,6,3] + [1] -> [1] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence([1,4,5,2,6,3], [1])));
            
console.log("[1] + [1,4,5,2,6,3] -> [1] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence([1], [1,4,5,2,6,3])));            


console.log("Using version 2:");

function findMaxCommonSequence2 (list1, list2) {
let indexList2 = {}; // Provides O(1) access to the indice in list2 for a given element
list2.forEach ((elt, i) => indexList2[elt] = i);

function find (list1, i2) {
    let ignore = new Set ();
    let maxLength = 0;
    let maxSequence = [];
    let i1 = 0;
    while (list1.length-i1 > maxLength) {
        let currentVal = list1[i1];
        if (indexList2[currentVal] >= i2 && !ignore.has (currentVal)) {
            ignore.add (currentVal);
            let rec = find (list1.slice (i1+1), indexList2[currentVal]);
            let sequence = [currentVal].concat (rec.maxSequence);
            ignore = new Set ([...ignore, ...rec.ignore]);
            if (sequence.length > maxLength) {
                maxLength = sequence.length;
                maxSequence = sequence;
            }
        }
        ++ i1;
    }
    return {
        maxSequence: maxSequence,
        ignore: ignore,
    };
}

return find (list1, 0).maxSequence;
}

console.log("[1,2,3,4,5,6] + [1,4,5,2,6,3] -> [1,4,5,6] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence2([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,4,5,2,6,3])));
            
console.log("[1,4,5,2,6,3] + [1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [1,4,5,6] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence2([1,4,5,2,6,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6])));

console.log("[1,4,5,2,6,3] + [1] -> [1] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence2([1,4,5,2,6,3], [1])));
            
console.log("[1] + [1,4,5,2,6,3] -> [1] returns ", 
            JSON.stringify(findMaxCommonSequence2([1], [1,4,5,2,6,3])));
```

Comment: I've edited the code and tested it on more cases, didn't see any issue so far:
(1) find() needed to be called in an outer loop, it makes sense because the lists can be empty but find() expects at least one element. The outer loop reuses the same general principles as find().  
(2) In find() there was an indice mistake, i1 shouldn't have been incremented before the first list1.length-i1 > maxLength test  
(3) I figured that this test subsumes the boundary check, which makes the loop condition less costly  
(4) did a bit of refactoring

Comment: I think there is a way to modify find() so that it behaves consistently even on the top level, but it would have to take a (possibly empty) list as an argument. At first glance I'd say it would be more expensive but I'm gonna give it a try.

Comment: So, it does work now, voting to re-open. I modified your question so that it is runnable, and with proof that it works.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a second version where find() works on a list, leading to a much shorter code. I have not noticed any reduction in performances on long lists.

Comment: Looks like you are going in a wrong direction. Hint: the problem is a Longest Increasing Subsequence in disguise, The trick is to figure out a comparator.

Comment: Oh I see, that's clever. Replacing the elements of list1 by their position in list2 and it's indeed a LIS problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @vnp If you turn that comment in to an answer, then I will upvote it, and this question will fall of my radar ;)

Comment: @konijn Appreciate it. However, such answer would be inappropriate here, because it provides no review.